# spidev.xfer2 in python gives IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: gpio, python, nrf24l01

I am currently trying to follow this [tutorial](http://blog.riyas.org/2014/08/raspberry-pi-as-nrf24l01-base-station-internet-connected-wireless.html?m=1). I keep running into errors for the RPi part. I have received several error related to SPI. I removed SPI from my blacklist and followed the instructions from a question asked on StackExchange to get to my current problem. The python code given in the tutorial imports the nrf24 library. I receive this error when I run (from tutorial):

> /home/pi/nrf24pihub/nrf24.py:374: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, >continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
>
> GPIO.setup(self.irq_pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "raspberryfriend.py", line 13, in
>
> radio.begin(0, 0,25,18) #set gpio 25 as CE pin
>
> File "/home/pi/nrf24pihub/nrf24.py", line 381, in begin
>
> self.write_register(NRF24.SETUP_RETR, (int('0100', 2) << NRF24.ARD) | (int('1111', 2) << NRF24.ARC))
>
> File "/home/pi/nrf24pihub/nrf24.py", line 239, in write_register
>
> return self.spidev.xfer2(buf)[0]
>
> IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Here is the [nrf24.py](https://github.com/jpbarraca/pynrf24/blob/master/nrf24.py) code. All I can gather is that the 'but' argument might exceed some storage limit, but the tutorial appears to have worked for others. How should I get around or fix this error? The error occurs in Python, so should I seek a solution from one of those forums?

Comment: are you running this as root? i.e. with sudo?

Comment: Yes, I ran the code as root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python spidev module has been broken (I think) since Linux kernel 3.15.x.

Its maintenance has recently been augmented with more support so I expect a new version shortly.

See [Read this if you use Python Spidev](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=680726#p680726).

Comment: I was able to update py-spidev from instructions I obtained at the link. There error is gone and everything seems to work as expected. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

It accepts only arrays as argument
Try to place your data in an array!