# SpiDev - spi.xfer([xxx]) -> Invaild argument error -> what?

Tags: python, spi

I got trouble with a seemingly dumb-proofly simple code:

```
import time
import pigpio
import spidev

DS = 17
STCP = 27
SHCP = 22
MR = 5

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 0)
spi.xfer([0b10011011])
```

Running the code gives error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "shiftreg.py", line 12, in <module>
        spi.xfer([0b10011011])
    IOError: [Errno 22] Invaild argument
```

I tried using spi.xfer(0b10011011), throws

```
TypeError: Argument must be a list of least one, but not more than 4096 integers
```

Using list(0b10011011) does not work, of course:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

As you see, I am only at the very beginning of the code (yust waned to try out how the default SPI setup works with a shift register), so there are unused variables and imports.
Since all my parenthesis are okey, the code complies well, I am pretty much in a WTF state now.

*((unrelated, but if I am here with this code...) Oh, and if you know any good rescource for controlling a shift register via SPI, please let me know.)*

Comment: The root cause is likely to be that given in the answer here http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27204/spidev-xfer2-in-python-gives-ioerror-errno-22-invalid-argument

Comment: @joan So you say this might be a SpiDev bug? It is strange because I have another code that uses it, and it works flawlessly. (And still, if the module is broken, I would expext the error happening in the module not in my code...) Does anyone know any good alternative? (I do not like it too much, the documentation is awful.)

Comment: It is odd that the same module works with other code - however I would upgrade the module.  The error is identical to the one I got before upgrading.  Your code mentions pigpio.  You could try its SPI support, see http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#spi_open.  It may be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Also, the first error `IOError` is passed on by the module.

Comment: Trying the update, right now apt-get updating (just in case...) Until it is finished, here is the code that works, in case anyone wishes to solve this puzzle. (It is for playing with a max7219-based led array.) https://gist.github.com/godot11/7ca8839943afd923f704

Comment: @joan It did not fix it, sadly. Also, if I am right, the updated SpiDev module on the link is for Python2.7, and I use 3.

Comment: @joan I know pigpio, worked a lot with it and it is avesome, but the documentation says: "Normally you would only use the spi_* functions if you are or will be connecting to the Pi over a network. If you will always run on the local Pi use the standard SPI module instead." So I thought I better not use it if I don't have to...

Comment: @user4729 Perhaps that is worded too strongly.  I wanted to caution that there will be more of an overhead using the pigpio SPI routines rather than the local spidev functions.  The overhead may not be significant in your application.

Comment: @joan I will use pigipio in this case (also it seems I don't even really have a choice... Adafruit has an SPi libary that seems to support software spi, but there is no known documentation...) I am planning to try pwm on the shiftregs (something like the ShiftPWM ardunio libary, of course by far not so efficient :D) and that needs as fast SPI as possible.